# Is it possible to align images in certain pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to fill a triangle with small icons of house.
I want to create something like this-
[image]

Is it possible to do this in Photoshop or any other software or I have to do it manually?

Comment: yes it is possible using a special plugin in Illustrator not photoshop and after that you could export it into photoshop. The plugin called [colliderscribe](http://astutegraphics.com/software/colliderscribe/)